# jenkins can't get the list

Tags: jenkins, groovy

jenkins parameter plugin

```
return ["DEV", "TEST", "STAGE", "PROD"]
```

above, it work but
jenkins can't get the list when you code looks that

```
def ENVS=["DEV", "TEST", "STAGE", "PROD"]
return ENVS
```

is there any good way to deal with it ?

Comment: You did not provide details to answer your question. Please add more details-

Comment: `def E*VN*S`; vs `return E*NV*S`. Typo?

Comment: yes , it's a typo